# Underlined Search Text Inside String Swift

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to make bold and underlined searched text inside the string. I have tried this solution but it just gives me an error. [image]

This is my configure

```
 func configure(model: SmartSearchGroupViewModel, searchedKey: String) {
    let boldUnderlined = NSAttributedString(string: searchedKey, attributes: [.font: UIFont.sfProTextBold(size: 15), .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
    let content = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: model.name)
    content.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.sfProTextRegular(size: 15), range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: content.length))
    if model.name.substring(from: 0) == searchedKey.substring(from: 0) {
        content.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: boldUnderlined.string.count))
    }
    groupNameLabel.attributedText = content
}
```

But I get an error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String.Index'

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: I have changed my code.

Comment: You add the underline effect `content.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: boldUnderlined.length))` everytime, even if there is no "match". Check before adding the effect if the string contains `searchedKey`.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String.Index' after I added a control.

Comment: `if let range = (content.string as NSString).range(of: searchedKey) { content.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 1, range:range) }` ?

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange')

Comment: `let range = (content.string as NSString).range(of: searchedKey); if rarnge.location != .notFound {}` or something like that?

Comment: I have created same functionality and it works fine. Let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done like this:

First initialize the attributed string with default attributes:

```
let content = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: model.name)
content.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.sfProTextRegular(size: 15), range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: content.length))

//Here, if you don't want to use the `NSRange`, you can use instead:
let content = NSMutableAttributedString(string: model.name, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.sfProTextRegular(size: 15)])
```

Then, to add special effects for search, you can use:

Solution 1:

```
let searchRange = (content.string as NSString).range(of: searchedKey)
if searchRange.location != NSNotFound {
    content.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: searchRange)
}
```

Solution2:

```
if let search = content.string.range(of: searchedKey) {
    let searchNSRange = NSRange(search, in: content.string)
    content.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: searchNSRange)
    }
```

The difference between Solution1 & Solution2, is the use of `range(of:)` applied on a `NSString` or a `String`, it will output a `NSRange` or a `Range`. Since `NSAttributedString` uses `NSRange`, solution one might be "quicker" to write.

Side note, if you also want to search for non-case sensitive, you can use `.range(of: searchedKey, options: .caseInsensitive)` (and even put the local parameter: `.range(of: searchedKey, options: .caseInsensitive, locale: .current)`.

I noticed on your code `NSRange.init(location: 0, length: boldUnderlined.string.count)`, be careful the count on Swift might no be the same of `length` in NSFoundation. Ie UTF8 vs UTF16 counting. So use `string.utf16.count` instead, or `length` directly.